# event.target.classList doesn't have indexOf method

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<button class="hello bello jello">start text</button>
<script>
$("button").on("click", function(event) {
    var lo = event.target.classList
    console.log(lo.indexOf("hello"))
})
</script>
```

I expected the above snippet to print, `0` but it threw out an error `lo.indexOf is not a function`.

Isn't event.target.classList typed as array?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no `indexOf` method, `classList` is arrayLike object. 
But there is `contains()` one:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 18):

The [`classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a [`DOMTokenList` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) and it doesn't have a `.indexOf()` method. Here are a few options:

#### Option #1

Convert the `DOMTokenList` collection to an array using the `Array.from()` method to check:

```
var hasClass = Array.from(event.target.classList).indexOf('name') > -1;
```

#### Option #2

Use the [`classList.contains()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to check:

```
var hasClass = event.target.classList.contains('name');
```

#### Option #3

Since the `.indexOf()` method exists on arrays, you can use the `.call()` method to invoke the method with using the `classList` (where the string `'name'` is the class you are checking):

```
var hasClass = [].indexOf.call(event.target.classList, 'name') > -1;
```

#### Option #4

This options has the most browser support since the [`className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is supported in all browsers.

The `className` property returns a string of the element's classes. You could use a regular expression to test if the string contains the desired class (this covers instances where the class `name` is the only class, and when the class `name` is separated by whitespace when there are multiple classes).

```
var hasClass = /(^| )name( |$)/i.test(event.target.className);
```

You could also just turn this into a function:

```
function hasClass (element, className) {
  return new RegExp('(^| )' + className + '( |$)', 'gi').test(element.className);
}
```

#### Option #5

If you're using jQuery, just using the [`.hasClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```
var hasClass = $(event.target).hasClass('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're using jQuery, use [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass) to check if the clicked element contains specified class.

Also, use `$(this)` inside event handler to refer to the element that is clicked.

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

```
$("button").on("click", function(event) {
    console.log($(this).hasClass('hello'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on a [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function:

```
event.target.classList.toString().indexOf('hello')
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
if (~event.target.classList.toString().indexOf('hello')) {
  // The target's class list contains the phrase 'hello'
}
```

---

> **Note:** This will also return true for classes such as: `helloworld` and `_hello_` (which is how [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) was intended to perform).

Comment: This worked great for me as I had to match partial class names.